# Segmentation fault while file copy in unix

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, file-handling

I am writing to copy text from one file to another in unix using C lang. Below is a a part of my code. when i execute the program i am getting  **Segmentation fault** error.

Any help appreciated..

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    int infile;
    int outfile;
    int n;
    size_t size;
    printf("Enter the Source file name: \n");
    scanf("%s",&argv[1]);
    printf("Enter the Destination file name : \n");
    scanf("%s", &argv[2]);

    if((infile = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY,0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Source file does not exist");
        return -1;
    }

    if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY,0644))>0)

    {
        printf("Target/Destination File Exists:\n \n ");

        //printf("Target Fiel Exists , Do you wish to Overwrite or Appened Data to it: \n \n               1=Yes(Overwrite),\n 0=No(Append):\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        if(n==1)
        {
            if((outfile=open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT |O_EXCL, 0644)>=0))
            {
                printf("File is Being opened in Overwrite Mode: \n      \n");//File is overwrited
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings and debug info : `gcc -Wall -g` ? Did you use the debugger `gdb` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's very, very unusual to read data into your `argv` array.  You probably shouldn't think about doing that.

Even if you really wanted to do that, the following would still be wrong:

```
scanf("%s",&argv[1]);
```

The elements of `argcv` are *pointers* to strings, so that function call will read a string into the memory that stores a pointer. The `argv[1]` elemetn will be invalid, adn in all likelihood the string that is input will overrun and trash one or more elements after that one.

Try something like:

```
    char infile_name[81];
    char outfile_name[81];

    printf("Enter the Source file name: \n");
    scanf("%80s", infile_name);
    printf("Enter the Destination file name : \n");
    scanf("%80s", outfile_name);
```

And adjust the rest of the references to `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

Comment: The loader may read the command-line arguments into a segment that is then marked read-only before creating a thread to run main()?

Comment: @MartinJames: no - the arguments are supposed to be writable, but unless you really know what you're doing, it's probably best to avoid that (for example - you can't depend on there being more memory than is necessary for the argument string).  Also, here the OP isn't writing over the arguments, he's writing over the pointer array. Again, that is writable, but not with character data.